# checking if your elemMatch regex conditions work

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a MongoDB query:

```
db.list.find({categories:{$elemMatch:{ "$regex":".*Bar.*", $not:/^Barbeque/}}}).pretty()
```

where it looks at the elements in the categories array and I think gets all documents where there is an element that contains "Bar" but none that contain "Barbecue". How to I check make sure that my query is correct?

Let me know if my query is wrong and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the end of string like this:

```
$not:/^Barbeque$/
```

rather than

```
$not:/^Barbeque/
```

because if any of file contains **(i.e. "Barbequee")**, it must return to your query result.

about *make sure that my query is correct or not*, i have no idea. But if your query is correct, mongo must return the value that matches the written query.

if something goes wrong, it must be that the logic in the query that results in mongo returns an unexpected value for you.

so check your query before you run it. :D